# how to filter data in sql based on percentile

Tags: sql, percentile

I have 2 tables, the first one is contain customer information such as id,age, and name . the second table is contain their id, information of product they purchase, and the purchase_date (the date is from 2016 to 2018)

```
Table 1
-------
customer_id
customer_age
customer_name
```

```
Table2
------
customer_id
product
purchase_date
```

my desired result is to generate the table that contain customer_name and product who made purchase in 2017 and older than 75% of customer that make purchase in 2016.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your flavor of SQL, you can get quartiles using the more general `ntile` analytical function. This basically adds a new column to your query.

```sql
SELECT MIN(customer_age) as min_age FROM (
SELECT customer_id, customer_age, ntile(4) OVER(ORDER BY customer_age) AS q4 FROM table1 
WHERE customer_id IN (
SELECT customer_id FROM table2 WHERE purchase_date = 2016)
) q 
WHERE q4=4
```

This returns the lowest age of the 4th-quartile customers, which can be used in a subquery against the customers who made purchases in 2017.

The argument to `ntile` is how many buckets you want to divide into. In this case 75%+ equals 4th quartile, so 4 buckets is OK. The `OVER()` clause specifies what you want to sort by (customer_age in our case), and also lets us partition (group) the data if we want to, say, create multiple rankings for different years or countries.

Answer (score 0):

Age is a horrible field to include in a database.  Every day it changes.  You should have date-of-birth or something similar.

To get the 75% oldest value in 2016, there are several possibilities.  I usually go for `row_number()` and `count(*)`:

```
select min(customer_age)
from (select c.*,
             row_number() over (order by customer_age) as seqnum,
             count(*) over () as cnt
      from customers c join
      where exists (select 1
                    from customer_products cp
                    where cp.customer_id = c.customer_id and
                          cp.purchase_date >= '2016-01-01' and
                          cp.purchase_date < '2017-01-01'
                   )
      )
where seqnum >= 0.75 * cnt;
```

Then, to use this for a query for 2017:

```
with a2016 as (
      select min(customer_age) as customer_age
      from (select c.*,
                   row_number() over (order by customer_age) as seqnum,
                   count(*) over () as cnt
            from customers c
            where exists (select 1
                          from customer_products cp
                          where cp.customer_id = c.customer_id and
                                cp.purchase_date >= '2016-01-01' and
                                cp.purchase_date < '2017-01-01'
                         )
            ) c
      where seqnum >= 0.75 * cnt
     )
select c.*, cp.product_id
from customers c join
     customer_products cp
     on cp.customer_id = c.customer_id and
        cp.purchase_date >= '2017-01-01' and
        cp.purchase_date < '2018-01-01' join
     a2016 a
     on c.customer_age >= a.customer_age;
```

Comment: thx for your response. after I run your query I get this notif `Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'where'.` its coming from where seqnum >= 0.75 * cnt,